# Using iptables, how can i open a port only when i'm in my home network?

Tags: networking, security, iptables, firewall, nixos

I want to host a service for syncing stuff between my laptop and my phone. Since I don't own a server, I decided i would host the services on my laptop. For my phone to be able to connect to that service, I need to open the corresponding port in my firewall, iptables. However, when I'm on a public network, I don't want to expose the service to potentially malicious traffic. I'd like to open the port, but only when I'm on my home network. Is that possible to do using iptables?

At my home network, my phone auto-connects to the wifi as soon as i come home. My laptop is connected via wifi all the time I am home and via ethernet only when i plug it into my docking station. Both devices get their IP address from the router via dhcp, but the router by default gives them the same IPs every time.

PS: NixOS-specific answers are appreciated, but i think I can figure the difference out on my own.

Comment: please tell more about your home network - is it wifi or ethernet, do you have a router you can configure, what kind of address your laptop receives (per dhcp?). When you are at home how do you connect your phone to internet?

Comment: Al alternate approach would to be use something like tailscale to have your laptop and phone always on the same private network regardless of where you are and not worry about dynamic firewall rules.

Comment: I just tried a webserver on my laptop and connecting to it with my phone on the same network. It works with
`sudo iptables -A INPUT -m mac --mac-source nn:nn:nn:nn:nn:nn -j ACCEPT` (put the MAC/WiFi address of your phone in nn:nn...). Add port, protocol, interface name if you want. Or do you see a problem with such approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest ping your router, check arp address.

It is likely that at boot, connection to internet in made, <s>so at boot time</s> on hourly basis use someting like

```
ping -c 4 myrouterip > /dev/null 2>&1
arp | awk '$1 == "myroutermac" { print $1}' | sha512sum > /tmp/sum.txt
if cmp -s /tmp/sum.txt ref.txt
then
   ## at home 
fi
```

where

- **myrouterip** is symbolic name of your router (*)
- **myroutermac** is mac address returned from `arp` from your home router
- `ref.txt` is a file that contains sha512sum (or whatever sul tou'll see fit) from `arp| awk ..` line

  (*) this suppose you don't go to place using same name of your router **and** router using same mac address

I expect you know

- your home router's name and how it appear on arp
- how to start a script at boot time (if not check on U&L )

Comment: this approach doesn't handle the case that i leave the home network without rebooting, which i do a lot.

Comment: 1) please add this to your question, 2) see my edit.